# SQL query filtered by COUNT

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables: comments and regions. The sql query is:

```
SELECT comments.region, 
    COUNT(comments.region)
FROM comments, regions
WHERE comments.region = regions.id
GROUP BY comments.region;
```

The result table is (id, COUNT(comments.region)):

```
1 | 3       
2 | 1
3 | 7
4 | 6
5 | 2
```

How I can add rule to filter all rows where COUNT(comments.region) > 5? Finally I need to get a summary table:

```
3 | 7
4 | 6
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(comments.region) > 5`

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT c.region, COUNT(*)
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN regions r
    ON c.region = r.id
GROUP BY c.region
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

**Notes:**

I replaced your implicit join with an explicit `INNER JOIN` using an `ON` clause.  As @GordonLinoff likes to say, you should avoid putting commas into the `WHERE` clause.  I also introduced table aliases into the query, which relieve us from having to write the full table name repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `HAVING`?

```
   SELECT comments.region, 
          COUNT(comments.region)
     FROM comments,
          regions
    WHERE comments.region = regions.id -- obsolete syntax: use JOIN instead
 GROUP BY comments.region
   HAVING COUNT(comments.region) > 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the HAVING clause

```
SELECT comments.region, COUNT(comments.region)
  FROM comments, regions
  WHERE comments.region = regions.id
  GROUP BY comments.region
  HAVING COUNT(comments.region) > 5;
```

See here for more details on HAVING clause https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp